# android_ndk tutorials

Tags: ros, transform, ros-indigo, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
CMake Error at /opt/roscpp_output/target/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2" with any of
  the following names:

    tf2Config.cmake
    tf2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "tf2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "tf2_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "tf2" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231784/android_ndk-tutorials/) by [shyoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26568/shyoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error was due to a name change on the tf2 package and it has been fixed [here](https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android/commit/37cbb37d58b6b33a3fc21121d3997fa202b55f49).

You need to pull the changes from the repo, run: `sudo rm -r output/catkin_ws` to delete the workspace and run the `do_docker.sh` script again.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0